# How block Youtube ads on Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, adblock

Any adblocker for Chrome blocks the annoying Youtube popup ads?

Comment: What is AD url? Add it to Privoxy. Also found https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6178 -- nasty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Adblock Plus.](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

There is chrome plugin called [YouTube Options](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-options/bdokagampppgbnjfdlkfpphniapiiifn?hl=en) you can use. It offers lots of options like disabling ads, annotation, captions and changing the layout of YouTube video.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the hosts file to block the video ads if you're on Windows:
http://www.lolloland.com/2012/12/12/technote-how-to-remove-video-ads-youtube/

Answer (score 0):

Another option: Configure DNS to use ADGuard public DNS servers.

No registration required.

Standard: 176.103.130.130 and 176.103.130.131

Family protection: 176.103.130.132 and 176.103.130.134